# THREE.js PerspectiveCamera focalLength off by a factor of two, inconsistent with FOV

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspectivecamera

In THREE.js we construct a camera using the following function

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
```

We know  from optics that the field of view of a camera is related to the focal length by the following equation

```
FOV = arctan(d/2f)
```

where `FOV` is the vertical FOV in degrees, `d` is the height of the image plane in mm, and `f` is the focal length of the camera in mm.

After reading [the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera) on the matter, it seems as though `d` is set by default to be `35mm / aspectRatio`.

We can express `FOV` like this

```
FOV = arctan((35/(width/height))/2f) = arctan(filmHeight / 2f)
```

As a sanity check, I printed the following value, to see if I would get back the input FOV of `75`.

```
Math.atan(camera.getFilmHeight()/(2 * camera.getFocalLength())) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

But.. this value comes out to be `37.50000000000001`

which is exactly half of the expected focal length of `75`.

So, I was wondering if I did the math wrong somewhere, or if I'm misinterpreting THREE.js's reported values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`.fov`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.fov) angle is the

> Camera frustum vertical field of view, from bottom to top of view, in degrees.

But what you calculate is, the angle of the center of the view to the top:

```
Math.atan( (camera.getFilmHeight()/2) / camera.getFocalLength())) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

[image]

this is indeed the half of [`.fov`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.fov):

```
fov = 2 * Math.atan( (camera.getFilmHeight()/2) / camera.getFocalLength())) * 180 / Math.PI;
```