# Aframe/Three fit to screen - calculate zoom

Tags: math, three.js, webgl, aframe, quaternions

I want to zoom the camera in Three/Aframe so an image fits to screen.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    this._camera = document.getElementById('camera').getAttribute('camera')
    this._ratio = this._assetWidth/this._assetHeight

    this._vFOV = window.THREE.Math.degToRad( this._camera?.fov || 80 )

    this._height = 2 * Math.tan( this._vFOV / 2 ) * this.data.distance
    this._width = this._height * this._ratio

    this._zoom = this._ratio > 1 ? this._width/window.innerWidth : this._height/window.innerHeight

    console.log(this._zoom,  this._ratio, this._width, window.innerWidth)
```

I've got to the part where I need to calculate Zoom so that the object fits to the screen, i.e. if it's landscape fits to width, if it's portrait fit to height.

I thought [this was the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059612/calculate-camera-zoom-required-for-object-to-fit-in-screen-height) but it's not. that's to calculate the camera position rather than zoom value.

I'm stuck on how you work out the zoom value.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fitting an object to the screen by:

- changing the camera FoV
- zooming the camera
- repositioning the camera / object

is quite similar once you understand where the formulas came from.
We'll use this neat image ([from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881693/three-js-perspectivecamera-focallength-off-by-a-factor-of-two-inconsistent-with)) as it covers all three topics:

[image]

**0. What do we want to achieve**

We want the object (the longer side of either its width or height) to cover the `filmHeight` - so it fits the screen.

**1. Recalculating the FoV**

In this case we do know the `focalLength` (camera distance from the object) and `filmHeight` (object width or height). We can calculate `fov / 2` thanks to our friend [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions):

`Tan (fov / 2) =  (filmHeight / 2) / focalLength` 
`=>`
`fov = 2 * ATan ((filmHeight / 2)) / focalLength * 180 / PI`

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("fit", {
    init: function() {
      const plane = document.querySelector("a-plane")
      const distance = this.el.object3D.position.distanceTo(plane.object3D.position)
      var height = plane.getAttribute("geometry").height
      var newFov = 2 * Math.atan((height / 2) / distance) * (180 / Math.PI); // in degrees
      this.el.sceneEl.camera.fov = newFov
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-plane position="0 1.6 -2" material="src: https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpg"></a-plane>
  <a-camera position="0 1.6 0" fit></a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

**2. Repositioning the object / camera**

Same triangle different variables. Now we want to know the `focalLength`:
`Tan (fov / 2) =  (filmHeight / 2) / focalLength` 
`=>`
`focalLength = (filmHeight / 2) / Tan (fov / 2)`

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("fit", {
    init: function() {
      const plane = document.querySelector("a-plane")
      const height = plane.getAttribute("geometry").height
      const fov = this.el.sceneEl.camera.fov * (Math.PI / 180);
      const newDistance = Math.abs((height / 2) / Math.tan(fov / 2))
      plane.object3D.position.z = -1 * newDistance;
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-plane position="0 1.6 -2" material="src: https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpg"></a-plane>
  <a-camera position="0 1.6 0" fit></a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

**3. Zooming the camera**

If we know what distance should the camera be from the object for it to fill the screen - we know what is the relation between the current distance, and the new one:

`zoom = currentDistance / necessaryDistance`

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("fit", {
    init: function() {
      const plane = document.querySelector("a-plane");
      const distance = this.el.object3D.position.distanceTo(plane.object3D.position);
      const height = plane.getAttribute("geometry").height;
      const fov = this.el.sceneEl.camera.fov * (Math.PI / 180);
      const newDistance = Math.abs((height / 2) / Math.tan(fov / 2));
      this.el.sceneEl.camera.zoom = distance / newDistance;
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-plane position="0 1.6 -2" material="src: https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpg"></a-plane>
  <a-camera position="0 1.6 0" fit></a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: since `a-frame` manages window / canvas resizing, I think there is no need to use the window width / height. At least it seems to work properly when i change a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfLaw86h/2/) window size

Comment: That is a stunning answer @Piotr

Comment: @beek you accepted the answer without any comment and I was worried it was  "meh, good enogh" :D I'm really glad if it helped, actually your question made me look it up and attempt to understand the math behind it.

Comment: best answer ever on Stackoverflow! Meant I could see which solution worked best and adjust accordingly! Thanks so much for your help!